# Installing Ubuntu on 3 partitioned flash drive

Tags: partitioning

I was wondering how I can install Ubuntu 14.04 on a 3-partitioned flash drive. I would like to have Ubuntu installed on one partition, whereas on the remaining partitions I'd have other live usb installed. Can YUMI do the trick? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

YUMI Will do this for you there are various ways to approach this issue. I myself use GRUB2 and add what I need. YUMI is a nice out of the box approach though. Why do you want to partition the drive ? you can make each live Disto persistent and it creates it's own space allocation.